# Bugs in touch-screen on Dell Developers Edition with 12.04?

Tags: touchscreen

I just got this 13" Dell XPS13-9333 laptop ( AKA Sputnik - http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/xps-13-linux/pd ). Personally, I was hoping to be able to use the touch-screen a lot, but it has been buggy to the point of being useless for everything from playing flash games to clicking on buttons and opening programs. I was wondering if these issues were just happening to me or if these problems were systemic across the model as a whole?

The touch-screen issues are organized according to number of fingers:

One finger touch issues:

1. Sometimes fails to click (or do anything) when you tap,
2. Sometimes drags instead of clicks (regardless of how high you set the drag threshold in "Touchpad and Mouse" or how quickly you tap the screen),
3. Randomly seems to double click (in a flash game that I was playing)
4. Mouse moves to an arbitrary point on screen just after a click occurs.

Two finger touch issues:

Two finger touch doesn't do anything, despite there being a functional three and four finger touch. On the touch-pad, two finger touch right-clicks. Shouldn't the same behavior occur on the touch-screen?

Three finger touch issues:

Sometimes three finger touch brings up these white arrows that let me move and resize windows. Other times, three finger touch does nothing. Somewhat inconsistent.

Four finger touch:

Perfectly brings up the Ubuntu launch menu every time. The only thing that works consistently is the four-finger touch gesture.

So, for anyone else with the Dell Sputnik, are these touchscreen issues just on my computer, or are they systemic to the XPS13 Developers Edition model as a whole?

p.s. If the issue is widespread, I would like for a bug report about it to please be filed. I tried, but there were too many procedures, and when I ran "ubuntu-bug" in the terminal I did not know how to classify it or what package the bug was coming from.

Dell's ProSupport team couldn't help me at all. I tried with them for several days.

Comment: Touch screens, being new technology, are a bit buggy on all OS. It typically varies with applications.